# How to transform termIndices to term using CountVectorizerModel.vocabulary in DataFrame ?

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-ml

I use CountVectorizerModel to create feature out of text to train in LDA

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|label|sentence                              |words                                            |features                                                           |
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0.0  |Hi I heard about Spark                |[hi, i, heard, about, spark]                     |(30,[1,5,6,7,16],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                            |
|0.0  |I wish Java could use case classes    |[i, wish, java, could, use, case, classes]       |(30,[5,9,11,13,24,26,29],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])            |
|1.0  |Logistic regression models are neat   |[logistic, regression, models, are, neat]        |(30,[4,14,18,21,22],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                         |
|1.0  |They are cats                         |[they, are, cats]                                |(30,[3,4,17],[1.0,1.0,1.0])                                        |
|0.0  |cat is only one cat in a group of cats|[cat, is, only, one, cat, in, a, group, of, cats]|(30,[0,2,3,8,10,20,23,27,28],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1.0  |cat is meowingful all day long.       |[cat, is, meowingful, all, day, long.]           |(30,[0,2,12,15,19,25],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                   |
|1.0  |cat                                   |[cat]                                            |(30,[0],[1.0])                                                     |
|1.0  |spark                                 |[spark]                                          |(30,[1],[1.0])                                                     |
|1.0  |spark cat                             |[spark, cat]                                     |(30,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])                                               |
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is topics

```
val topics = model.describeTopics(3)
println("The topics described by their top-weighted terms:")
topics.show(false)

+-----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|topic|termIndices |termWeights                                                      |
+-----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|0    |[2, 5, 7]   |[0.03954771670945735, 0.03941180947330347, 0.03888945410782809]  |
|1    |[3, 23, 20] |[0.038638315281474093, 0.037879704408459995, 0.03774139169021561]|
|2    |[9, 28, 21] |[0.04232988497943897, 0.04007287769364308, 0.039937267948921336] |
|3    |[18, 5, 15] |[0.03705824484750299, 0.036890803795663674, 0.036716976690456406]|
|4    |[15, 2, 19] |[0.051298533195568756, 0.049034272085125466, 0.04766027890074748]|
|5    |[8, 15, 28] |[0.039784800740184825, 0.03919450578763458, 0.03747537818514296] |
|6    |[26, 7, 10] |[0.03914211167490289, 0.038519959566040284, 0.03777486155909476] |
|7    |[3, 2, 25]  |[0.03824521540169412, 0.03809586773398763, 0.03744203244313033]  |
|8    |[8, 28, 1]  |[0.04141091418342947, 0.040997706216988956, 0.03925572055141317] |
|9    |[16, 24, 23]|[0.04106798576100414, 0.03947867647938766, 0.036999875515655097] |
+-----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And their schema

```
 root
 |-- topic: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- termIndices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- termWeights: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

I would like to create another column (named term) to display String instead of indices.

So, I create a function

```
val lookup2 = ((a:Array[Int]) => {
    a.map(x => cvModel.vocabulary(x))
})
```

The function lookup2 work well when I test with one case

```
lookup2(Array(1,2,3))
res194: Array[String] = Array(spark, is, cats)
```

I tried to turn the function into UDF and apply to whole column

```
val lookupudf = udf(lookup2)
topics.withColumn("term", lookupudf($"termIndices")).show()
```

It does not work

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<int>) => array<string>)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1058)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:359)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedProjection.apply(Projection.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedProjection.apply(Projection.scala:30)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$23.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1191)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$23.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1185)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1055)
  ... 105 more
```

What do I need to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

The array in DataFrame was WrappedArray. So I should define my udf as follow

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val lookup3 = ((a:WrappedArray[Int]) => {
    a.toArray.map(x => cvModel.vocabulary(x))
})
val lookupudf3 = udf(lookup3)
```

Then use the udf to create new column

```
topics.withColumn("term", lookupudf3($"termIndices")).show()
```

It should work

```
+-----+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|topic| termIndices|         termWeights|                term|
+-----+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    0|   [2, 5, 7]|[0.03954762152543...|     [cats, are, hi]|
|    1| [3, 23, 20]|[0.03863839536342...|    [is, long., use]|
|    2| [9, 28, 21]|[0.04232988718372...|[could, they, cla...|
|    3| [18, 5, 15]|[0.03705824666867...|      [of, are, one]|
|    4| [18, 3, 15]|[0.04114420013742...|       [of, is, one]|
|    5| [8, 15, 28]|[0.03978480361117...|      [a, one, they]|
|    6| [26, 7, 10]|[0.03914211373502...|  [logistic, hi, in]|
|    7| [3, 25, 23]|[0.05067447986285...|    [is, day, long.]|
|    8|  [8, 28, 1]|[0.04141091392312...|    [a, they, spark]|
|    9|[16, 24, 23]|[0.04106809235206...|[meowingful, java...|
+-----+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```